# Making a case-insensitive "like" query using the mongodb driver in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm looking to make a query like mentioned in the title with an array of data.

I have this line working..

```
collection.find({"name": {"$in":[/papa JOhn's/i,"Taco Bell"]}}).toArray(function(err, items) {
```

However, the data is going to be dynamic and fed into the query as an array

```
restaurant_data = [rest1, rest2 .... restn]
```

I want to essentially have something like

```
collection.find({"name": {"$in": /restaurant_data/i }}).toArray(function(err, items) {
```

### My Attempt..

```
let test_data = ['papa john', 'taco bell']
//Get an array of the restaurant names here

collection.find({"name": {"$in": test_data.map(element => {

  /element/i

})}}).toArray(function(err, items) {
```

### My working attempt!

I got it doing this... Not sure if it's the most efficient

```
let test_data = ['papa john', 'taco bell']

collection.find({"name": {"$in": test_data.map((element) => {
  var regex = new RegExp(".*" + element + ".*");
  return regex
})}}).toArray(function(err, items) {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
collection.find({"name": {"$in":
  restaurant_data.map(e => new RegExp(e, 'i'))
}}).toArray
```

has better chance to work. Note that `/bla/i` will match `blabla` so

```
collection.find({"name": {"$in": [/bla/i] } })
```

will match documents with name `blabla` Not sure this is what you want or not.

Comment: Awesome, I got a similar working solution, but yours is much cleaner. Thank you !

Comment: Side-note.. I believe it's new RegExp not new Regex

Answer (score 0):

If you're using mongodb 3.2+ I'd recommending you using the property [Collation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/collation/) as using Regex might make the queries quite slower, you can use it in both creating indexes as well as querying:

```
db.peeps.createIndex({UserName:-1}, { collation: {locale:'en', caseLevel:false, caseFirst: "off"} )
db.peeps.find({UserName:'bob'}).collation({locale:'en', caseLevel:false, caseFirst: "off"}) // 3 results!
```

However, as I've faced this problem as well when I tried using collation it made my queries at least 2 times slower so I ended up sticking with inserting lowerCase data in mongodb and then validating and using toLowerCase in the payload fields instead of using Collation.